# Convert Hexdump to string in c

Tags: c++, c, hex, hexdump

Is there a way to convert a hexdump e.g. aec4d2f3c6a4e70ea6cea074f65812d2a34b180cc92b817edcd867167e7a91c5beb942f0 
to a string in c so that every two hexadecimal digits make a char? If so, what?

Comment: Just decoded the string char *str = "Someone will do my homework for a few reps more :-)";

Comment: You can convert a hexdump to a **byte array**.  You can't necessarily convert it to a **string**.  What if you have an 0x00 byte?  Or bytes that aren't valid in your character encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reads from stdin and prints to stdout:

```
int main() 
{
    int ch;
    while(scanf("%2x", &ch) == 1)
        putchar(ch);
}
```

I think you can modify it easily yourself for your specific source and destination requirements.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways:

```
size_t unBytes = strHex.size() / 2;
std::string strResult(unBytes, 0);
for (size_t i = 0; i < unBytes; ++i)
{
    std::istringstream in(strHex.substr(2*i, 2));
    int byte = 0;
    in >> std::hex >> byte;
    strResult[i] = byte;
}
```

Comment: You got me -- I can't tell if this is a joke.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: It's C++ =) of course it can be made much shorter and faster. I've just copy-pasted it from one of my programs

Comment: @Nawaz Thank you. Originally unStart and unEnd had some offsets

Comment: @ssmir: OK.  I realise `istringstream` necessitates the call to `substr()` (in an ideal world it would have a constructor taking an iterator pair, which would avoid this, but that's not your fault), but please at least preallocate enough space in `strResult` and use `strResult[i] = byte;` directly, rather than wastefully going via `encoded`.  You don't need `encoded` at all.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thank you. Originally I needed this vector, but now - not.

Comment: @ssmir: That looks much healthier :)

Answer (score 0):

Use scanf with `%hhx` repeatedly. See `man scanf`.